vuetify trouble with active element highlight
i have a very simple template
main.js
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import * as components from 'vuetify/components'

const vuetify = createVuetify({
    theme: {
        defaultTheme: 'light',
    },
    components,

})

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(vuetify);
app.mount('#app')

App.vue

<template>
  <header>
  </header>

  <main>
    <v-app>
      <v-app-bar >
        <v-app-bar-nav-icon></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
        <v-app-bar-title style="flex: 0;min-width:200px">Horizon Phuket</v-app-bar-title>
        <v-btn >
          Home
        </v-btn>
        <v-btn >
          Best deals
        </v-btn>
        <v-btn>
          test 1
        </v-btn>
        <v-btn>
          test 2
        </v-btn>
      </v-app-bar>
    </v-app>
  </main>
</template>

as you can see, the active element is filled completely with black color

and the same template at vuetify sandbox is ok

VITE v5.4.9
vuetify: 3.7.2
vue: 3.5.12

was missed
import 'vuetify/styles';

the documentation does not describe the need for this import, it was difficult to find information
